# App Thinning XCode 7 iTunes Connect

Tags: app-store-connect, xcode7, testflight, app-thinning

I'm using **Xcode 7.0.1 (7A1001)** and noticed that Submitting my app now goes through an App Thinning stage and a folder gets created with the numerous .ipa for the different devices supported by our app.

When I'm downloading the app from **iTunes Connect Test Flight** for testing, I don't see any reduction in size. Can someone shed some light on whether the app size should be smaller? Am I doing something wrong in the configuration or will it only be smaller when downloaded from the actual **App Store**?

Thanks!